# Excepción StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium, testing

Estoy intentando acceder a una lista de productos de una categoría. Cuando ésta solo tiene un producto dentro, el proceso se hace correctamente. Pero si la categoría tiene más de una producto, me salta la excepción: StaleElementReferenceException.

El código es el siguiente:

```py
def dessert(self, driver, data_json):

        list_categorias = ["menu-category_POSTRES", "menu-category_CERVEZAS Y VINOS"]

        for c in list_categorias:
            category = driver.find_element_by_id(c).find_elements_by_class_name("product-name")

            for cat in category:
                # falta algo
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cat)
```